# Could not load type 'test.request'

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, code-behind, inheritance

Having some problems with my asp.net application. I get this error every time: Could not load type 'test.request' when I try to run it in the browser. My project name is "test" and my class is "request"

The code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb"     Inherits="test.request" %>
```

and the code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class request
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim conn As New SqlConnection

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    getXMLString()
End Sub

Sub CloseDatabase()
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Sub ConnectToDatabase()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbSQL").ConnectionString
    conn.Open()
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `request`needs to be in the namespace `test`.

Your markup states `Inherits="test.request"`

Comment: VB little rusty ;-) test in the markup refers to your project and is correct. Can you access any controls on the page from the request class? for instance set the text of a label?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by controls but probably. Sorry, i'm really new to this.

Comment: You'll probably have a label or a textbox on your page. Can you do `Me.YourLabel.Text = "blabla"` in the Page_Load of your request class? Or does it give a compiler error?

Comment: uhh it gives a a syntax error. I don't understand why my inherent does not match up with test.request when i try and submit my html form in the browser

Comment: What do you mean by "submit my html form in the browser"? I've just made a small sample app and when I run it in Visual Studio, everything works as expected with exact the same asp.net markup that you have. So the issue must be somewhere else...

Comment: I have 2 radio buttons on an html page and they're supposed to correspond to data in my sql database. So selecting button "A" will pull the correct data from the database etc. When i submit my html form with one of the buttons selected, it gives me this    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb"     Inherits="test.request" %>

Comment: Can you add the relevant code of your HTML page to your question?

Comment: I cant seem to edit the code in my question so here it is:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Choice</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:  #BBC4CC">
    <form action="WebForm1.aspx" method="get">
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="requestchoice" value="Request A"   checked="checked"/>Request A
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="requestchoice" value="Request B"   checked="checked"/>Request B
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Sumbit Query" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Added the page to my visual studio project and works like a charm. Maybe you can create a new project and start from scratch? I was also wondering why you used a seperate page instead of the code behind file `WebForm1.aspx.vb`. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. I'll have to start it over tomorrow then. A separate file for the HTML as opposed to writing it in the ASP.NET file?

Comment: Also my solution file was named differently than my project file. If that would affect the inherit error at all...?

But just to let you know, I created the project all over from scratch and its letting me get past the error!!!

Although i have more more kinks to work out with my vb code which i wrote on the fly, at least it's progress! Thanks!

Comment: That could indeed have been the issue. And about your vb.code: give it a try and if you're stuck, plenty of people here that can help you solve it. ;-)